# Visually Select two things at once in vim

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

Let's say I have got a line of text like this

```
Hello World "How are you" World
```

Now, i want to know, if there's a way to select everything outside the quotes, at once? So, I am expecting something like this where the bolded text is the selection

> **Hello World** "How are you" **World**

I know it is possible but i am not able to find a way to get this done. 
I am thinking of doing something like select both parts individually and join them somehow.

My goal in this is to be able to create a motion that can delete everything except the stuff between " or ' as a operator pending motion. So, the operation can be Delete, Yank or Cut/Change. So, is there any other way to solve the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. In Vim there can only be one selection at once, although there exists a plugin [multiselect](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=953) that claims to do what you want. I have never tried it however.

Comment: I want to create a operator pending motion to delet everything in the line except the ***How are you*** . Is it possible in any other way, then?

Comment: visually select the **How are you**, store in register a. delete the line. put register a

Comment: That's the regular way. I know that. But i want to create a motion for that. So, i am basically looking to visually select that and do some action on that. Like we do in operator pending mode motions

Comment: I may want to do, **y** or **c** or **d** on the selected area, not just delete

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop I did intentionally use **store** it does not say, whether to use **y** or **c** or **d**. BTW: I don't unserstand, why you couldn't let a function do that.

Comment: I am trying to create a motion, not a function. So, i need something extensible. So, in future if i have to do something else, i can just target the same motion instead of writing a different function for that.

Answer (score 0):

Place cursor between double quotes, then

```
yi"   # Yank text between double quotes 
dd    # Delete line
"0p   # Paste register 0
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: That's the regular way. I know that. But i want to create a motion for that. So, i am basically looking to visually select that and do some action on that.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Jens answer:

```
yi"   # Yank text between double quotes 
V     # Select line
p     # Paste yanked text
```

Comment: Again, that is not what i need. I need to select the part inside, so that i can run various commands